# Getting acces to List<T> in model in ASP .Net Core MVC 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, entity-framework-core

I want to do an simply ASP .Net Core MVC APP.

I have two models:

```
public class Farming
{
    [Key]
    public int    Id                 { get; set; }
    public string Localization       { get; set; }
    public List<Animal> Animals      { get; set; } //i want to get into it 
    public List<Worker> Workers      { get; set; } //from cshtml file
}

public class Animal 
{
    [Key]
    public int      Id                  { get; set; }
    public Species  Species             { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate           { get; set; } 
    public bool     Sex                 { get; set; } 
    public DateTime ImpregnationDate    { get; set; } 
}

public class Worker 
{
    [Key]
    public int      Id                  { get; set; }
    public string   FirstName           { get; set; }
    public string   LastName            { get; set; } 
    public string   Position            { get; set; } 
    public float    Salary              { get; set; } 
    public DateTime EmploymentDate      { get; set; } 
    public DateTime EndOfEmploymentDate { get; set; } 
}
```

I setting up my database, it works ok. In `dbo.Animals` (`dbo.Workers works too)` in SQL Object explorer everything works pretty fine:

[image]

What i want to do, is to get acces into `List<Animal> Animals` and list of `Workers` from`Index.cshtml` page genereted internally in ASP .Net Core MVC in another `List.cshtml` file. Controller is genereted by Scaffolding too.

My `Index.cshtml` (i short it a little)

```
@model IEnumerable<Farm.Models.Farming>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
//foreach loop here with "item"
<a asp-action="List" asp-route-id="@item.Id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Localization)</a>
```

Method for going to `List.cshtml` from `FarmingController.cs`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> List(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var farming = await _context.Farms.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (farming == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(farming);
    }
```

So, how to get acces into `Models.Farming.Animal` and `Models.Farming.Worker` from imported `@SolutinName.Models.Farmin` in `List.cshtml`?

**EDIT1:**

I tried to get acces to Animal in this way:

```
var animal = await _context.Animals.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.FarmingId == id);
//i get `id` poperty from func `<IActionResult>` that i mentioned higher in this question
```

But i get information from Visual, that `Animal` dont have definition `FarmingId` (that is true, look at `Animal` model) but it exist in `dbo.Animals`. Im new in Core, any ideas?

**EDIT2:**

I edited database to this form, now it works better:

```
public class Farming
{
    [Key]
    public int    Id                      { get; set; }
    public string Localization            { get; set; }

    public List<Animal>      Animals      { get; set; }//
    public List<Worker>      Workers      { get; set; }//
}

public class Animal 
{
    [Key]
    public int      Id                       { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate                { get; set; } 
    public bool     Sex                      { get; set; } 
    public DateTime ImpregnationDate         { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("Farming")]
    public int      FarmingId                { get; set; }
    public Farming  Farming                  { get; set; }
}

public class Worker //pracownik
{
    [Key]
    public int      Id                  { get; set; }
    public string   FirstName           { get; set; }
    public string   LastName            { get; set; } 
    public string   Position            { get; set; } 
    public float    Salary              { get; set; } 
    public DateTime EmploymentDate      { get; set; } 
    public DateTime EndOfEmploymentDate { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("Farming")]
    public int      FarmingId           { get; set; }
    public Farming  Farming             { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to be okay, however try to explicitly include the animals

```
 Farm theFarm = _context.Farms.Include(f => f.Animals).Where(f => f.Id == farmId);
```

the object theFarm will contain all fields of the farm and also the list with animals. and farmId is the id of the farm you want to get.

use this to get all farms with their animals:

```
var theFarms = _context.Farms.Include(f => f.Animals).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Im pretty new in ASP so i need a little more detailed answer :D

What i tried to do: 

`var farming = _context.Farms.Include(f => f.Animals).Where(f => f.Id == farmId);` but it didnt find `farmId` in `FarmingsController.cs`.

Comment: I edited my answer, because i was not detailed in my question

Comment: try id instead of farmId its the value you pass into your function. try to use more descriptive names, it will make your life easier